# Why do I get "Undefined method `take' for Array" in Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

I'm not sure why I get this error, since it does seem to be an array in Ruby 1.8.7.

Here is the relevant code:

```
rows.each_with_index do |row, index|
    if (index == 0) then
        log "Found the following slow statements (took over #{slow_query_threshold} seconds):"
    end
    row_data = row.strip().split('|')
    connections = row_data[1].split(', ')
    n_more = '... and #{connections.length - 3} more' if connections.length > 3
    log %{[#{row_data[0]}] on #{connections.take(3).join(', ')} #{n_more}}
end
```

Which gives me this error:

```
2013-04-10T05:36:45.04Z : Found the following slow statements (took over 5.0 seconds):
/myscript.rb:111: undefined method `take' for ["App15(28.39sec)"]:Array (NoMethodError)
     from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `each_with_index'
```

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 supports `take`: `RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"` `%w[a b c d].take(3)
=> ["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: Seems like the ruby version may be older than 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be running on 1.8.6. Upgrade, or [`require 'backports/1.8.7/enumerable/take'`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports)

Comment: Was running on 1.8.5 because the #! in my script pointed to a different version than `which ruby`.